# Get value of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to exact the value of a column in pandas and plot them, I coded like that:

```
traffic = pd.read_csv('traffic.csv')
traffic.columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Zone', 'Potential']
X = traffic.iloc[0:579, 0:1]['X']
Y = traffic.iloc[0:579, 1:2]['Y']
Z = traffic.iloc[0:579, 3:4]['Potential']

fig = plt.figure()
for x, y, z in zip(list(X), list(Y), list(Z)):
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize = Z, alpha = 0.5)
plt.show()
```

And got a `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`. Now it seems it gives me a data with tails or something (if I `print()` them in the bottom there'll be some `Name: X, dtype:float64`), so failed the `for` loop.

So how can I get the value of a column?

The data is like that(copied from the `.csv` file):

```
413 359 A   1.7
403 343 A   2.1
383.5   351 A   2.2
381 377.5   A   1.7
339 376 A   2.1
335 383 A   2.5
317 362 A   2.4
334.5   353.5   A   2.4
333 342 A   2.1
282 325 A   1.6
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas' matplotlib wrapper

```
traffic.plot(x='X', y='Y', style='ro', markersize='Potential', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

**Edit** :

Apparently, pandas wrapper does not allow markersize to be variable.

Though, you can use a standard scatter plot :

```
plt.scatter(df['X'],df['Y'], s=df['Potential'])
```

Comment: Idk... it gave me `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Potential'`

Comment: try: traffic['Potential'] = traffic['Potential'].astype(float)

Comment: Apparently, makersize don't accept variable size.
You can either, fix the size or use standard scatter plot.